# Overwriting and dynamically writing a has_many in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have an issue where I have a polymorphic table that is associated with a class that has been namespaced but I still want to obtain the records even if the `_type` was set to the old class name. Say the polymorphic table is `Seeds` and a `Tree` has_many :seeds.

```
Class Tree
  has_many :seeds, as: :seedable
end
```

So when I write `Tree.first.seeds` the `seedable_type` is `Tree`. How do I customize this so that the seedable_type is `<whatever_I_want_it_to_be`?

Comment: Is a datafix out of the question? e.g make a DB migration or rake task to update the type with the new type? (I know it doesn't really answer the question, just an alternative suggestion)

Comment: yeah it's not on the table right now... since other teams will have to change their queries using the database and I don't want to do that just yet if there's a solution.